# How to catch StorageException in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase storage with flutter. If the upload operation fails for whatever reason (e.g. exceeds size limits set in console), it causes a StorageException.

I want to do something like this:

```
try {
  final uploadTask = ref.putFile(docFile);
  taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
} on StorageException catch (err) {
  // Do something 
}
```

But there isn't any `StorageException` type and I can't find a way to catch any and all exceptions. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have cloud firestore imported before referencing StorageException

Comment: Also kindly mention the cloud firestore version

Comment: Yes cloud firestore is imported and I'm using this dependency ^0.12.10+2 (so should be the latest compatible version)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following instead.

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' as firebase_core;
try {
  final uploadTask = ref.putFile(docFile);
  taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
} on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch(e) {
     if (e.code == 'permission-denied') {
        /// Real permisssion-denied handling
        print('User does not have permission to upload to this reference.');
    }
    if (e.code == 'the-error-code-printed-to-console') {
        ///the-error-code-printed-to-console handling
        print('printing what you want');
    }

}
```

This handles errors and checks if it's due to permission. If you are looking for another cause, you can just print the `e.code` to the console first, copy the code and check if the code copied previously from console is equal to `e.code`.

Answer (score 0):

try catch doesnt work very well, I solved it like this:

```
}, onError: (e) {
        debugPrint('Exception::: ==========>>>>>>> ${e.toString()}');
      });
```

It get it that way